# Running Spark inside Web Application may throw “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded”

Tags: apache-spark, tomcat, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

We're running Spark inside a war-packed web application running on Tomcat.
Spark is pulling data from Cassandra using the DataStax connector - here are our dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

The problem is we get a lot of "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" errors, when Spark is trying to process data (but not always)::

```
      org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 18, localhost): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy$$anonfun$writeObject$2.apply(HashMap.scala:508)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy$$anonfun$writeObject$2.apply(HashMap.scala:507)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy.writeObject(HashMap.scala:507)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)

     Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1314)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply$mcZ$sp(RDD.scala:1416)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1416)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$isEmpty$1.apply(RDD.scala:1416)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.isEmpty(RDD.scala:1415)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:501)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.isEmpty(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
```

Other posts discuss the possibility to set "driver-memory" for Spark - but how is this configured when running within a web application on a local single node??
Since we included Spark in our application there's also a significant amount of memory being used - adding up over time - could there be a leak in Spark??

The Tomcat has -Xmx6144M set, which should be plenty for our data sizes - but maybe the driver or executor (which we believe cannot be an issue on a local node) need more memory?!?!

We presume it's a Spark configuration issue. But maybe there are some best practices we could follow - eg. run even a single local Spark node outside the war??

Comment: What are the values for your Spark configuration currently ? You can see those on the web UI of Spark.

Comment: [Spark Executors](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiMFdjY3luaHJHZmc).                                      [Spark Environment](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiN0oyenU2and2RW8).                                         That's the existing conf - notice no settings for spark.driver.memory or spark.executor.memory!!  ...and still how do we set these for Spark within Web App (no spark-defaults.conf or shell cmd-line)??

Comment: You can set those values either programmatically by using the `SparkConf` object, or you could provide those through the command line or a property file. Check out this [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), it is well explained. You should try increasing the `spark.executor.memory` and see how it goes (default is 1gb).

Comment: Yeah, that was actually our initial question - how do we set new Spark conf for Spark embedded in war?? Turns out when it's running in local mode it's necessary to set Spark memory settings when JVM is initially setup (when SparkContext is setup it's too late and there's no config file or shell), so when running in Tomcat we simply add these as java options: eg.-Dspark.driver.memory=2g

Comment: As I said, you can set it in your code by providing a SparkConf to your SparkContext, or when submitting applications, via the command line. How do you interact with Spark in your war ?

Comment: We have a DataRepository that constructs a JavaSparkContext, which is uses to load and process data from Cassandra. BUT the spark configuration has to be set PRIOR to constructing the SparkContext, as a local single node Spark resides inside the Tomcat JVM, which has been setup with memory constraints beforehand. With these Tomcat Java options: [Tomcat Settings](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiLWI0Uk9fOTRHclE) - the Spark UI states that memory is set accordingly. HOWEVER the driver executor still only has 1140.4 MB of storage memory :/

Comment: ...and the application still crashes occasionally with "GC overhead limit exceeded". This happens when the Tomcat process reaches little over 2Gb of mem. Here's a few takes of the dump: [Memory Overview](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiY0NESzd4dTZIOEE) & [Memory Objects](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_e9YTMgramiQm5XWkJpWURablE). Spark contributes to almost all of the consumed memory and especially the SizeTrackingAppendOnlyMap of one of the Spark Executors. Why is the JVM stopped at only 2Gb and how come Spark uses such a large map, which the JVM's GC cannot handle??